# String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm struggling with SSMS 17 and SQL Server 17

I have just added some data into a row (multiple columns). When I move away from the row in SSMS, it commits fine. If I try to change any column, I get the error message

> No row was updated.
>   The data in row 24 was not committed.
>   Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

A quick review of the row shows that I'm not hitting any limits with the nvarchar cols

I have a text column but I can add a single character and the issue still occurs

Even if I try to change a bit column from 0 to 1, or an int column from 100 to 10, the same error message is shown.

The fact SSMS/SQL Server accepted these values initially suggests that the data is valid (based upon the constraints).

I don't have any odd plugins other than SQL Prompt so I don't think that's the cause.

I'm very confused as to why I'm seeing this message?

**Edit**

The same message even shows when I try to delete the row via SSMS.

Running a query to update/delete works fine.

Comment: Could you add the query where you are changing the bit from 0 to 1 and the table definition?

Comment: Randi, doing it all manually via ssms

Comment: Show the whole error message. Try to make the same update statement in a query window instead of using the crutch UI. It's possible the first line indicates where the error is happening; it's probably a trigger. If you apply CU12 and enable trace flag 460, [there is a better error message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/) that will give you a better indication of where the error is happening. I don't know if this better error message will bubble up, in full, to the crutch.

Comment: @AaronBertrand updated for the entire message. I attempted the query. It works fine... It's only via SSMS it has a wobbly

Comment: You need to help out here. When you say "attempted the query" where do you mean? When you say "via SSMS" where do you mean? The Edit Top N Rows grid and a query window are both "via SSMS." If the query works in a query window, but not with the edit N rows UI, that sounds like "doctor, it hurts when I do this." In order to troubleshoot that you'd need to show the actual query behind the grid you're trying to use (e.g. if it's a view or an ad hoc query) and/or trace the actual commands being sent to SQL Server. Or just use a query window and ignore what bad things that crutch is doing.

Comment: ...and again, check the table for a trigger. You could have something silly that checks the application name (or logs the application name!) and since the grid and query window identify themselves as different applications, quite possible the latter works but the former doesn't fit.

Comment: I have not added any triggers. I don't even know how to set up triggers. Within SSMS, if I expand the table in question, and the expand triggers, nothing happens to the triggers 'folder' as it has no children. As such, I *guess* this means no triggers?